# zero's inbetween int literal in C

Tags: c, hex, bit-manipulation, literals

What does the following mean in C programming language?
I understand, that in my first line I have a hex-literal
I don't really understand what my 2nd line is doing. Without actually running the code, how can I find out what this code is doing? I'm studying for an exam where I will have to do this on paper.

```
int aaa = 0x5c0000a3;
printf( "%08x %08x\n", (aaa >> 12), (aaa << 16) );
```

Comment: Since you asked in the context of a paper test... I assume that you can figure out how often `printf` is referenced in the test. You should probably sit and read the official docs and a couple intermediate tutorials, because a lot of the internals of C can be exposed thru trying to get your data output. (sorry, my C is so rusty, I can't give an answer, just advice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second line:
">>" indicates a bit shift to the right, "<<" is a bit shift to the left.
So it's going to print a string to the console with the value of aaa shifted 12 right then shifted 16 left.

To expand: convert the hex value to binary, shift every bit right 12, convert to an int with 8 places.
Then shift all bits to the left 16 places and convert again.

Answer (score 0):

these are the bit-shift operators or simply [shift-operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Shift_operators)

- Right shift (>>)
- Left shift (<<)

now your code

```
int aaa = 0x5c0000a3;
```

in binary `aaa` will look like this

```
1011100000000000000000010100011
```

in `printf`  there are two expressions the first expression `(aaa >> 12)` shifts 12 bits towards right filling 12 bits from the left most side to zeros, resulting in a binary value like

```
1011100000000000000
```

which when converted to hex will results in `0x5C000`, the corresponding format specifier for this is `%08x` which will pad zeros from left and will print `0005c000` to console

similar thing happens when `left shift` applied, where `aaa` is shifted towards left while padding 16 zero zero bits from right.